# Using installed gems in Ruby with 'require'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I do something like `sudo gem install json`. Then I do `irb`. Then I do `require 'json'`. Then it says `no such file to load -- json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this first:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

RubyGems is a dependency manager as well as an installer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that RubyGems itself is loaded, for requiring gems to work.

There are [several ways](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70) to do this. You could `require 'rubygems'` explicitly in each file you want to use the gems in, but that might get to be a pain. Or you could pass `-rubygems` into `ruby` when you execute it, but again, you'd need to remember to do that each time.

The best way would probably be to set the `RUBYOPT` environment variable to `rubygems`. For instance, you may add the following line to your `.profile`:

```
export RUBYOPT=rubygems
```